# how to create a dynamic array of structs in C

Tags: c, struct

I want to send a struct of symbol from one function to other functions, and i want to create an array that every cell will point to a different values of the following struct:

```
typedef struct symbol_def
{
    char*           sym_name;
char*           sym_type;
unsigned short  sym_address;
char            sym_is_ext;
}symbol;
```

I'm trying to run this code:

//function-1

```
void compile_input_file(char* input)
{
symbol* curr_symbol;
    //Intalize curr_symbol struct
    curr_symbol = (symbol*)malloc(sizeof(symbol));
    //memset((void)curr_symbol, 0, sizeof(symbol));
    parse_command(line, &parser, curr_symbol, &index);
}
```

//function-2

```
void parse_command(char* line, parse_params* parser, symbol* curr_symbol, int* index)
{
    sym = symbol_table_create(curr_symbol, "directive", sym_label, '0', index);
}
```

//function-3

```
symbol* symbol_table_create(symbol* curr_symbol,char* s_type, char* label, char is_ext, int* index)
{
    int temp = *index;
    curr_symbol = (symbol*)realloc(curr_symbol,sizeof(symbol*)*(temp+1));
    curr_symbol[temp].sym_type = s_type;
    curr_symbol[temp].sym_name = label;
    curr_symbol[temp].sym_address = 0;
    curr_symbol[temp].sym_is_ext = is_ext;
    temp++;
    *index = temp;

    return curr_symbol;
}
```

The problem is that the curr_symbol gets override all the time.
my purpose is to build a table of symbols, that in every iteration on the code i'll add another cell to the array

any ideas?

Comment: Unless it's known up front how many entries there will be, I'd use a list rather than an array...

Comment: the number of entries is unknown

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem, with the `realloc` It should be `curr_symbol = (symbol*)realloc(curr_symbol,sizeof(symbol)*(temp+1));` You were actually allocating it sizeof `pointer` which is 4 Bytes.

A Piece of Advice `Realloc` is a costly operation you should use it only if necessary and not on every instance 
you could `malloc` in function3 instead of function1. If you do so you dont even need to pass the pointer via function2.

or else put a check to see if `realloc` is really necessary or not. Eg:- Check if the pointer is allocated memory. `if(ptr!=null){ //realloc }` This can work as a checking case too.

Best of Luck. :)

Comment: There's absolutely no guarantee that the size of a pointer is 4 bytes.

Comment: Ok It may or may not be.
I just wanted to highlight his mistake